# calilng echo through execv() prints extra character

Tags: c, exec, fork

I wrote a small program to test my knowledge of fork / exec / wait, but the program is behaving very strangely. Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t child = fork();
    if(child != 0) {
        printf("this is the parent\n");
        int status;
        waitpid(child, &status);
        return status;
    }
    else {
        char* const args[] = {"/bin/echo", "hi"};

        execv("/bin/echo", args);
    }
}
```

The output I see is:

```
this is the parent
hi 0 0
   0 1
```

Where those 0's and 1's are one character shown on my Linux terminal. I've tried explicitly adding a \0 at the end of each string, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Does anyone know why I am seeing those extra characters?

Comment: `waitpid` requires three arguments, how could you compile that with only two?

Comment: I didn't compile with -Wall. If I do I see warning: implicit declaration of function ‘waitpid’ among other errors

Comment: That's because you don't `#include <sys/wait.h>`, and compiler has to guess that this is a function of two arguments. And probably the call is performed incorrectly then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to terminate your `args` array with `NULL`:

```
char* const args[] = {"/bin/echo", "hi", NULL};
```

Otherwise `echo` wouldn't know where to stop reading its arguments.